# Am I criticizing by saying this?

Tags: present-perfect-progressive

If I visit someone in the middle of the day and they look like they have just woken up, can I say, "Have you been sleeping?" or does that sound like I am criticizing? Should I just say, “Were you asleep?"

Comment: It depends. Are you talking to a friend or someone you don’t know? In any case you might avoid making direct comments and say: “is this the wrong moment for a visit?”

Comment: Indeed the second one is more polite but that too can be offensive. It is totally dependent to whom you are talking. even better option is what @user5768790 has suggested. or you can say "Have I disturbed you?"

Comment: Are you asking out of concern, and wanting to apologize for disturbing them? Or are you making fun of their messed-up hair? Both questions pretty much mean the same thing – either one could be asked for a few different reasons. Whether it sounds like “criticizing” depends less on the wording and more on your tone and facial gestures.

Comment: Could you maybe give me an example of these reasons? This is really interesting, because I realize it is a matter of culture. In the Netherlands, where I live, people are very straightforward, a bit too direct maybe.

Comment: Example of the reasons? If I’m visiting my friend Dave, and he had a rough night, I might say, “Gee, Dave, you look awful! You look like you just got out of bed!” If he’s a good friend of mine, he would probably take that as the good-natured joking around it’s intended to be. But I’m not got going to say that if I'm checking in with my neighbor who I know has been taking care of her elderly sister, the cancer patient. In that case, I’d be much more sympathetic: “I’m sorry, did I catch you at a bad time? I didn’t mean to wake you up.” You haven’t provided much context.

Comment: "Have you been sleeping?" sounds like you're asking about their health, and should only be used with close friends. "Were you asleep?" is less problematic, but it's preferable to use only when it's very evident that they were, in fact, asleep. It would be offensive to ask this question of someone who was not sleeping because they might think you're accusing them of laziness.

Comment: How do you mean "asking about their health"?